# Prevent overlapping on an undefined number of generated objects in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-button, android-relativelayout

I'm writing a program that, for now, generates buttons at the touch of a preexisting button on a relative layout. There can be an indefinite number of such generated buttons.

I need to prevent them from overlapping. How do I do it so that it also scales with the screen size?

Comment: Show your code and layout.

Comment: Since RelativeLayouts need their Views to reference the related View for positioning in relation to it, I'd suggest you use a LinearLayout, in this case. Just for ease.